# Getting Facebook profile page for non-profit by launching iPhone App using alphabetical user name

Tags: facebook

Trying to bring up Facebook profile for non-profit group using the Facebook App if it exists on the iPhone, else use Safari. The webpage works in Safari, and is of form "www.facebook.com/LMNOpqr", but trying "fb://profile/LMNOpqr" doesn't work.

I tested using a friend's 10 digit Facebook ID "fb://profile/1234567890", which does work. Is there some extra syntax for an alphabetical name, or is this just not possible, and we need the explicit 10 digit number for the account?

We don't have a Facebook SDK on the development machines, and I think the customer wants to keep this minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I would be careful using fb://profile/1234567890 as when I tested it, it only worked if a user has previously opened the page on their phone from the Facebook app. If they hadn't it would return a blank page.   It's also not documented anywhere by Facebook so they may break it in the future without any notice.  That was also the only url I could get to work, not any kind of name. So if you are going to use this method, just grab the id easily from the fan page by going to http://graph.facebook.com/pagename